troubleshooting Huawei Matebook touchpad/Ubuntu 24.04
Similar to this question, but not I think identical (different model, different symptoms). (My cursor does move, the problem is not with a touchscreen or with the touchpad locking up after some time ...
Almost-new Huawei MDG-X Matebook (14"), running Ubuntu 24.04.
Symptoms: jumpy touchpad. Cursor jumps, machine senses mouse clicks and function-key presses even when my hands aren't (as far as I can tell) near the touchpad. (emacs was yelling me a lot about "XF86AudioMute not defined".)
I think I've tried "disable touchpad while typing" in the touchpad settings, but it would be preferable to fix the root cause of the problem if possible ...
If there's a better driver/fix for my settings, how would I find out what it was? Any further diagnostic suggestions?
Output of dmesg:
[    1.715437] input: BLTP7840:00 347D:7840 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-BLTP7840:00/0018:347D:7840.0001/input/input4
[    1.777519] input: BLTP7840:00 347D:7840 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-BLTP7840:00/0018:347D:7840.0001/input/input7

xinput:
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master kn `eyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

If I run evtest and select the touchpad I can get a string of events like this when I press the heels of my hands on the spaces next to the touchpad, without touching the keypad itself ... (maybe getting some pads to isolate the heels of my hands from the body of the laptop would help?)
Event: time 1724001563.786586, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.793913, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2916000
Event: time 1724001563.793913, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.800864, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2922000
Event: time 1724001563.800864, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.807950, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2928000
Event: time 1724001563.807950, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.815130, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2934000
Event: time 1724001563.815130, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.822089, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2940000
Event: time 1724001563.822089, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.829107, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 1718
Event: time 1724001563.829107, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1718
Event: time 1724001563.829107, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2946000
Event: time 1724001563.829107, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.835812, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2952000
Event: time 1724001563.835812, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.842783, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 1717
Event: time 1724001563.842783, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1717
Event: time 1724001563.842783, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2958000
Event: time 1724001563.842783, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1724001563.849941, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1724001563.849941, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1724001563.849941, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER), value 0
Event: time 1724001563.849941, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 2964000
Event: time 1724001563.849941, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^C

